# How to install latest nvidia drivers (xorg edgers doesn't work)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I 'm trying to install latest nvidia drivers (352) but it doesn't work.
I tryed following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

When I tipe the last command I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Unable to locate package nvidia-352
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why xorg edgers doesn't work

Comment: There is no more `nvidia-352` package in `xorg-edgers`.

Comment: which version are available

Comment: Read the duplicate link. You can install all drivers form another ppa.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

And it also makes sense to remove `xorg-edgers`

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: Is it better to recommend removing the PPA with `ppa-purge` instead of `add-apt-repository -r` which seems to remove the package source file only?